# using a checkbox with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a simple true false checkbox working and I am having some trouble.

First off it is using the custom class tep_draw_checkbox_field which is defined as follows:

```
 function tep_draw_checkbox_field($name, $value = '', $checked = false, $compare = '') {
    return tep_draw_selection_field($name, 'checkbox', $value, $checked, $compare);
  }
```

ok so then in the php I have:

```
<tr>
    <td class="main"><?php echo "Made in Canada?"; ?></td>
    <td class="main"><?php echo '&nbsp;' . tep_draw_checkbox_field('made_in_canada', '1'); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Above all that I have the blank array stored into the variable $pInfo (taking out the unnecessary):

```
$parameters = array('products_name' => '',
                       'canadian' => '');

$pInfo = new objectInfo($parameters);
```

And I have the query of the product stored in an array variable called $product

```
$pInfo->objectInfo($product);
```

and here's where things get real shaky.. Here is where I try to send whether it is checked or not to the variable:

```
 if (isset($pInfo->canadian)) {
    $canadian =  1;
  } else {
     $canadian = false;
  }
```

I think that is all that is needed. I am not getting the database to recognize the checked box, and I am also not getting the box to reflect if the database is true (1) or not?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing `<?php echo '&nbsp;' ..` when it could just be (much easier) `&nbsp; <?php ...` instead?

Comment: ehh was working on that quickly and missed it there was something else in there before. so I just edited it out. is there a difference though?

Comment: in the big picture, no. small picture, it does force php to do a poinless string concatentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you posting back to the same page?  All you should need to do is say

```
if(!empty($_POST['made_in_canada']) {
  // It's made in canada
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little? this still requires the code to add the true to made_in_canada no?

Comment: Sorry I realized I was posting canada instead of made_in_canada and it seems to be working now, except that the checkbox is not reflecting if it is checked or not in the database.

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay.  the reason this works without checking the value is because it doesn't get set in the request if it's not checked -- so if it's there, it must have been checked.  If you have two checkboxes with the same name but different values, that's when you'd check the actual value to see which one was checked (or both)